# Пуш-уведомление по установленному времени

Tags: android, android-notification

Всем добра! Ребят, это снова я и мне нужна Ваша помощь. Я полностью переосмыслил работу со временем, с пикерами даты и прочего полезного. Имеется следующий код.

---

**1. Метод работы со временем:**

```
         ...
         info = (TextView)mBottomSheetDialogTime.findViewById(R.id.info);
         pickerDate = (DatePicker)mBottomSheetDialogTime.findViewById(R.id.pickerdate);
         pickerTime = (TimePicker)mBottomSheetDialogTime.findViewById(R.id.pickertime);
         Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
         pickerDate.init(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), null);
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
             pickerTime.setHour(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
             pickerTime.setMinute(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
         } else {
             pickerTime.setCurrentHour(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
             pickerTime.setCurrentMinute(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
         }
         buttonSetAlarm = (Button)mBottomSheetDialogTime.findViewById(R.id.setalarm);
         buttonSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(), pickerDate.getMonth(), pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(), pickerTime.getHour(), pickerTime.getMinute(), 0);
                    else cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(), pickerDate.getMonth(), pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(), pickerTime.getCurrentHour(), pickerTime.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    if(cal.compareTo(current) <= 0) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Date/Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else scheduleNotification(getNotification(), cal);
                }});
       ...
```

**2. Метод работы уведомления:**

```
private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, Calendar targetCal{
        info.setText("\n\n\n"+"Alarm is set@ "+targetCal.getTime()+"\n");
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationPublisherBroadcastReceiver.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisherBroadcastReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisherBroadcastReceiver.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        else alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

**3. Receiver**

```
    public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver{

        public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
        public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
            int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
            notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**4. Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher" android:process=":remote"/>
```

**5. getNotification()**

```
private Notification getNotification() {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationPublisherBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", getString(R.string.notificationtitle));
    intent.putExtra("text", getString(R.string.notificationtext));
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.time)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notificationtitle))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notificationtext))
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    return builder.build();
}
```

---

Вся проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю `buttonSetAlarm`, в котором вызов уведомления `scheduleNotification(getNotification(), cal);` уведомления приходит сразу же, а не когда я назначил время, и еще не показывается `Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` из `receiver` (Есть подозрение на не поддержку API. У меня стоит поддержка от 15 до 23 версии, на данный момент тестирую на 23).
Где я ошибаюсь? И что мне сделать, чтобы исправить? Любая помощь будет бесценной!

---

P.S. клевая [статейка](https://medium.com/@ifr0z/workmanager-notification-date-and-time-pickers-aad1d938b0a3) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так регистрируется алярм для разных версий android-a.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) 
           alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
         else 
           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Плюс посмотрите какое значение достает  `pickerDate.getMonth()`. Если возвращает 5 (май), то надо вычесть 1, так как в календарь месяца сетятся от 0 до 11.

Comment: Сделал, но все равно не пашет:( Почему то ` Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` не показывается из ресейвера

Comment: а Вы под дебагом смотрели? Он точно туда заходит? Время правильное сеттите в календарь?

Comment: Все, заработало! Ваше условие помогло:) Спасибо Вам большое), ошибка была в том, что я ресайвер держал в другом package...Все как всегда

Comment: =) Бывает. незачто

Comment: Правда забавная ситуация получается, он сразу выводит уведомление и потом выводит уведомление в нужное время, не знаете случаем где я косячу опять?)

Comment: Cтранно.. А один и тот же алярм выдает? Просто возможно это старые выкидываются

Comment: один и тот же получается, дублируя

Comment: попробуйте полностью снести приложение и переустановить. Проявится ли бага снова?

Comment: переустановка не помогла

Comment: getNotification() прикрепите к коду

Comment: прикрепил getNotification()

Comment: notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build()) вот и вылетает первый раз

Comment: его удалить можно?

Comment: Угу, вот это удалите из метода getNotification()  NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

Comment: Огромнейшее Вам спасибо! Помогло! :) и наконец-то все работает как надо. Без Вас бы еще мучился и мучился...