# Notification в определенное время

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Хочу что бы Notification в приложении появлялся каждый день в одно и тоже время каждый день. Например, в 10 утра. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Я использовал  ресивер на timetick ещё можно alarmmanager использовать. Интересны другие решения.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520478/205563 Вот тут я подробно расписал как делать)) ток правда я использовал timepicker и datepicker, но алгоритм понятен. P.S. ответ тоже посмотрите там важная инфа

Comment: обновил свой вопрос-ответ там, чтобы удобней было изучать

Comment: @iFr0z спасибо!

Comment: @Lucky_girl рад был помочь)

Comment: вам надо решить 2 отдельных задачи: 1. Как выполнить действие по расписанию. 2. Как показать уведомление.