# Как прикрутить Notification к Receiver?

Tags: android, android-notification

Помогите, пожалуйста! Есть класс с ресивером, но нотификация никак не хочет прикручиваться(

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Uri alarmUri = 
    RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null)
    {
        alarmUri = 
  RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    final Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, 
  alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();
    //Сама нотификация: 
   NewNotification n = new NewNotification();                                                    
   n.notify(Alarm.this, "Напоминание", 1);
}
```

Ошибка:
 Change signature of notify(<s>Context</s> **Alarm**, String, int)

**NewNotification** стандартный код из Android Studio

```
 public class NewNotification {

private static final String NOTIFICATION_TAG = "New";

public static void notify(final Context context,
                          final String exampleString, final int number) {
    final Resources res = context.getResources();


    final Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);


    final String ticker = exampleString;
    final String title = res.getString(
            R.string.new_notification_title_template, exampleString);
    final String text = res.getString(
            R.string.new_notification_placeholder_text_template, exampleString);

    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)


            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_new)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setLargeIcon(picture)
            .setTicker(ticker)
            .setNumber(number)
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            context,
                            0,
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("Main.class")),
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .addAction(
                    R.drawable.ic_action_stat_share,
                    res.getString(R.string.action_share),
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            context,
                            0,
                            Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                                    .setType("text/plain")
                                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Dummy text"), "Dummy title"),
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))

            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notify(context, builder.build());
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
private static void notify(final Context context, final Notification notification) {
    final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG, 0, notification);
    } else {
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG.hashCode(), notification);
    }
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
public static void cancel(final Context context) {
    final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_TAG, 0);
    } else {
        nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_TAG.hashCode());
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: А в чем проблема то? Из вашего кода не видно где вы прикручиваете нотификацию и где проблема собственно возникает

Comment: что такое `NewNotification` - покажите его код

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520478/205563

Comment: Добавила код к описанию вопроса

Comment: Всё, сама разобралась))